# Is it possible to have a single version of VSCode when using Anaconda?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

For different reasons, I recently decided to start using VSCode more generally. So far, I was only using it when willing to add the description of my commits in Git. Setting VSCode as the default editor was pretty straight forward.

The problem comes when I decided to open VSCode from Anaconda in order to use it for Python.
For instance, when opening from Anaconda, I can use the VSC terminal just like the Conda prompt, and therefore select the virtual environment that I need to use.

When launching it from "the computer" (not Anaconda), it does not have all those extensions plus I can´t select environments from conda (commands do not exists).

This actually makes sense when I think about it (those environments were created in conda), but I do not understand why I cannot get rid of the "local" version and just install VSCode from Anaconda and, from there, set it to be default text editor for Git.

My question therefore are, is there any way to simply have a single version of VSC (Anaconda), or make the "local" to detect the one from there? Also, can I set git to use VSC from Anaconda as the default text editor?

FYI: I found no other way to have VSC than downloading it from its webpage, installing it and then it seems to be avaiable in the Anaconda Navigator straight away.

Thanks!

Comment: "When launching it from "the computer" (not Anaconda), it does not have all those extensions plus I can´t select environments from conda (commands do not exists)." what does this mean *exactly*?

Comment: [Does this help?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) I think you're going the wrong way, you want a single version of VSCode configured to use different environments.

Answer (score 0):

Vscode is an editor, and Anaconda is the **A set of pre established and configured packages can be installed on the operating system**.

You can create multiple virtual environments and switch them in vscode.

Read the [docs about python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_virtual-environments) for more details.

You can use the shortcuts "**Ctrl+shift+P**" and type "**Python: Select Interpreter**" to switch the python interpreter.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that when I opem VSC outside Anaconda, it does not show the environments that I created in Conda (which is normal). Not sure I can find a way to find the conda environment when not using Anaconda?

Comment: @JaviCV Can't the conda environment be displayed in the python interpreter list according to the docs?